# DATEADD in JDBC template

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm trying a query select with **jdbc** and **spring boot**,

I want select informations where my  creation date value is LESS than now minus 30.

I tried like this :

```
SELECT *  
FROM informations 
WHERE lastTreatment < DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())
```

I have an error like this :

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Anyone has idea ? Thanks

Comment: tag your dbms , your query looks ok ,

Comment: it's oracle JDBC

Comment: That's invalid for Oracle to begin with. Try `lasttreatment < current_timestamp - interval '30' minute`

Answer (score 1):

You claim Oracle but looks like you write MS SQL Server or MySQL. There is no such function DATEADD in Oracle and neither is there a GETDATE function. To add x days in to a date in just do *date+x*. In this case you just need a fractional part of a day, so just add an x which yields the need fraction. For 30 minuets that would be *30/(60*24)* or (30 minuets/ (60 minuets per hour * 24 hours per day). As for GETDATE just use SYSDATE.
So your query becomes:

```
SELECT *  
FROM informations 
WHERE lastTreatment < sysdate-(30/(60*24));
```

Comment: I already tried sysdate but it's the same things, it seemsSYSDATE is not recognized with JDC query and spring boot

Comment: Then the problem lies either with the JDBC and/or Spring boot. Sysdate has been basic in Oracle since version 8 released in June 1997(I suspect much older but a quick internet search could not find an earlier reference.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe missing ; at the end?

```
SELECT *  
FROM informations 
WHERE lastTreatment < DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE());
```

Comment: No with Java we don't put this " ;" ,
It's JDBC template, the problem is with date but I don't know what exactly

Comment: its not java syntax , its sql syntax, It should be part of your query string.

Comment: If it's Oracle SQL as tagged, it doesn't have any `;` character. The `dateadd` thing makes me wonder if it's something else though.